# Dereference relative to end iterator

Tags: c++, std

Is this the correct way to dereference the last item in a range?

```
std::string getName(Foos::const_iterator& begin, Foos::const_iterator& end)
{
    return boost::apply_visitor(Detail::NameGetterForFoo(),*--end);
}
```

Presuming that I always have something in the vector.

Comment: You're aware, that `--end` changes the `end` iterator, right? It's not the same as `*(end - 1)`

Comment: Note that this will decrement the original iterator. You may want to pass by value, or use `*std::prev(end)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are always sure to have something in the container, use std::prev on end to obtain the iterator before it, then decrement that. Here's how I would write your block of code:

```
std::string getName(Foos::const_iterator begin, Foos::const_iterator end)
{
    // Assert: begin != end.
    return boost::apply_visitor(Detail::NameGetterForFoo(),*std::prev(end));
}
```

Edit: also containers support the .back() member function as well. If you pass in your container instead of an iterator range you can use that instead. This may be helpful as it seems like in this block of code all you really want is the last element of a container. e.g.

```
std::string getName(Foos const& foos)
{
    // Assume Foos is a standard container with front() and back() and that
    // it is non-empty.
    return boost::apply_visitor(Detail::NameGetterForFoo(), foos.back());
}
```